# Getting lost chrome android data back

Tags: data-recovery, chrome-for-android

My mom uses my android phone sometimes, and I guess yesterday or the day before she had reset one or more of my apps, including chrome, since all my open tabs and history is gone. I was not syncing my data and I'm desperately trying to get that data back (open tabs, history etc.). Is there anyway I can recover that data? I would be forever indebted if you can help me out! It feels like a hopeless situation, but I had about 80 tabs open that I lost, and I'd like to get them back!

She also used chrome yesterday and today, and all that shows up in history is that data.

Edit: I now actually think she hasn't reset chrome, after checking in settings chrome is latest version and it also shows a lot of data there, as well as cache. I'm not sure what happened to my tabs and history, but if it could be recovered by adb, can you help me out?

Comment: Were you signed into your Google Account before the reset/clear?

Comment: @MorrisonChang I wasn't logged in chrome.

Comment: If it was not synchronized to the google, and your phone was not rooted, you are probably out of luck. If it was synced, then the focus would be to get the data form the google. If it was rooted, you are still likely out of luck, but you might recover some data on the block-level, in binary fragments (it is hard).

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica Can I use adb to get that data?

Comment: I would still check the Google account that you used for the Google Play Store for browser history just in case. If you didn't sign into Google Play Store, yeah not much hope.

Comment: @MorrisonChang I am signed into Play Store, but I'm not signed in chrome, history was not syncing.

Comment: @Adventurer If it was not rooted, then probably not. The problem is that is was probably not simply hidden, but re-initialized.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica I think in chrome desktop, last session's tab list can be recovered... I was thinking of something like that for android too.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica If the app was not actually reset, then that list might still not be re-initialized, right?